# Seperate words/numbers from symbols in Python

Tags: python, regex

In python 2, I would like to take a string, and store it in an array, with the delimiter being a change from words/numbers to symbols, as well as spaces, or vice versa. Hoping for a function which could do this. Example:

```
"54 3 'hello world' 5+4"
```

would return

```
["54", "3", "'hello world'", "5", "+", "4"]
```

I have used `re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)` to get a list of all the words/numbers separated, but I am stuck when it comes to getting the symbols sorted out.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is no inbuilt function to handle this case, you need to create one for you. And do you meant `store` instead of `sort`?

Comment: I have used `re.findall(r"[\w']+", Script)` to get a list of all the words/numbers separated, but I am stuck when it comes to getting the symbols sorted out. @Bhargav Rao

Comment: @user15888 add it to your question

Comment: Yes, I did mean store, editing that now. @Anmol_uppal

Comment: what are the potential symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use a workaround like below, but you didn't specify all possible symbols.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "54 3 'hello world' 5+4"
>>> re.findall(r"('[^']*'|\w+|[^\w\s]+)", s)
['54', '3', "'hello world'", '5', '+', '4']
```

A more strict way of doing this would be:

```
>>> re.findall(r"('[^']*'|[a-z0-9]+|[^a-z0-9\s]+)", s, re.I)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
x="""54 3 'hello world' 5+4"""
print [x for x in re.split(r"[ ](?![^']*'(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)|([+*-])",x) if x]
```

You can try this through `re module`.

Comment: Wish I could accept more than one answer, nice job!

Comment: @BhargavRao did this directly on my compiler.Dont worry it works :)

Comment: My apologies haha, I have pretty much no reputation, and up voting requires 15, I will revisit and upvote when I have 15 rep.

Comment: Are you vks? Or has someone else hacked your account! Without DEMO, your answer looks soo incomplete!. Lol. Anyway upvote from myside :)

Comment: @BhargavRao hahahahah m d same :P why didnt you try this one....had gone thru ur answers :P ....u seemed to be a python wizard :)

Comment: Lol, No wizardry from my side (Still 20yrs). I was confused in this, coz I had used `ply`, in which you can do all this and even more in seconds. So didn't know whether to use `ply` for this or not. (I would have to explain to the OP about that module then ;) )

Comment: @BhargavRao whoa!!!! will look into that module!!!!!!!!! `ply` thanx a lot :) u r a wizard :)

Answer (score 2):

You can split with the following pattern :

```
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'(?<![a-zA-Z]) |([\+\-\*\\])',s) if i]
['54', '3', "'hello world'", '5', '+', '4']
```

`(?<![a-zA-Z])` is [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that split based on spaces that not preceding by any word character!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yours works fine but I can only accept one. :)

Comment: Do revisit at 15 rep ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao i hope! but after 10! i think i'm loosing my tendency to rep! ;)

Comment: You can actually group ur `+-*\` together

Comment: @vks How i can group and still i have them in split list ?

Comment: Like i did in my answer :)

Comment: @vks ahan yep , thanks but yours is wrong you need to escape your operands!

Comment: No.inside character class u don't need to

Comment: @vks oops yeah, i had this doubt too, do you know what was my fault? i use `[+-*]` that raise `sre_constants.error: bad character range
` but i must use `[+*-]` :D

Comment: @KasraAD `-` inside character class defines a range.So either you keep it at end or escape it.In your case it forms an invlalid rage from `+` to `*`